# PostgresSQL pg_stat_all_indexes record every index usage?

Tags: postgresql

Does PostgresSQL `pg_stat_all_indexes` record every index usage?

Is that configurable whether record every usage or sampling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It records every index usage, most of the time.

The PostgreSQL statistics collector listens on a UDP socket, and backend processes send it a datagram whenever they have something to report. While every index usage will be reported, there is no guarantee that all these reports are received. So if there is high load, messages may get lost.

But to answer the unasked question that I suspect to be behind this question: if `pg_stat_all_indexes` reports an index as never scanned, [you can drop it (if it does not back a constraint, is unique or is based on an expression)](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/get-rid-of-your-unused-indexes/).